# Why is SendKeys bad practice?

Tags: security, methodology, sendkeys

When dealing with signal interrupt issues, the `Ctrl-C SIGINT` would close my ssh session. (I'm sure you've all heard this before, and I'm certainly sick of it too - so I won't bother explaining that further.)  In short, I could achieve the desired result by using the `SendKeys` function.

Now many people discourage using SendKeys unless it is *absolutely necessary*. The method is often bashed for security flaws, but the only viable reason I see (but don't fully grasp) was that it could fill the keyboard buffer - which if poorly handled, could lead to undesired system results.

Every other reason was just the generic "It causes security issues. Don't use it." I read that it could significantly help to block both mouse and keyboard interaction during the process, such as using BlockInput.

I feel that undesired system results could result from nearly anything these days. I want to know, specifically, why it is such a "bad practice" to use this approach when programming, and to actually understand these security flaws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *used* to be a valid security concern before UAC. For instance, you could issue ATL+CTRL+DEL or to copy information from one application to a malicious one or run key scripts without the user's consent.

It's likely though, that many applications (even direct x) will block SendKeys and you will get security exceptions.

Use **SendMessage** or **SendInput** as alternatives.

With the introduction of .NET 3 and user account control, these gaps have been closed. In fact, windows 8 was just rated secure for the  government this week.

Some applications like Outlook might raise exceptions (for good reason) if you try to sendkeys. Also, there's likely no harm in *your* application using it, the potential harm is malicious software misusing the feature.